# Review audit badges

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-request, review-audits

To promote the better reviews there should be some badges for success audit reviews.

Currently if many audit fails user is blocked to review for two days, but some positive for successful audits there should be badge to appreciate the fair reviews.

like there is a badges range for review count:

> [image: badges]

There should be badges(count can be adjusted according to frequency of audits):

- 10 audit Pass: Bronze badge
- 25 audit Pass: Silver badge
- 75 audit Pass: Gold badge

In this way user reviewing the badge with a proper way get appreciated and others are also motivated to do proper reviews rather than click, click and click.

**Edited**

No negative badge but positive badges can appreciate reviewer

Comment: Audits are there to make sure you aren't blindly reviewing posts. I don't see why users should be rewarded for reviewing posts correctly when there are already other badges available to them for that specific purpose.

Comment: I'll get a gold in 3 weeks :)

Comment: There certainly shouldn't be a badge for negative behavior. It gets lumped in and displayed with the other badges in several places.

Comment: @Asad: Read it again, the badge is for non-negative behavior

Comment: @Manishearth Take a look at the original question. There was a badge suggested for failing audits

Comment: @Asad: oh oops :)

Comment: The mess that review badges caused in the first place is why we have audits. This seems like it would promote gaming of the audit system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like this idea, but I think it should be far more exclusive to prevent people trying to game the situation to get more badges.

As for this being an award for not "not 'not bad'" behavior, I don't believe that is the case.  This is a reward for people who really take reviewing seriously.  It is the only reward for high review quality.

**Badges**

- Eagle Eye (silver): 20+ passed audit tests, 90% accuracy.
- The IRS (gold): 50+ passed audit tests, 95% accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

Audits are there to trap folks blindly reviewing stuff. Badges are to award good behavior, not "not bad" behavior.

Besides, this will make more people know about the audits and they'll probably write scripts to detect and pass audits (these probably already are there, but to a lesser extent)

Comment: +1 for *not "not bad" behavior*.

Comment: Think you meant not "not "not "not " not "not bad"""""... I think, at least.

Answer (score 4):

Reviewers are already [awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2278/custodian) [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer) [for reviewing](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2279/steward). Why should we award folks multiple times for the same task?

Comment: Because robo-reviewers only review to get badges. If they only get awarded for reviewing no matter how they review as it is currently, they will just click on any button to get the badge. If they also get rewarded for reviewing correctly, they might pay more attention to how they review.