# Making review more fun with more badges

Tags: feature-request, review, badge-request

StackOverflow has a growing number of closure review queue. Increasing review count and making review a more funny task can be done by creating some more badges. since we (mostly) all love badges, that can be good. Since SX network have some control mechanisms on review like:

- *Review checker*: A previously reviewed question to check if you are careful enough
- *Limit*: 40 review vote limit that is removed in 10 hours.

Thinking all that following can be good to have badges

- **Argus Eyed**: Passed x *review checker* test (on a single category) in a row without any failure

  - 3: Bronze badge
  - 7: for Silver badge
- **Hard Tracker**: Filled 40 review vote limit (on a single category) on x consecutive days

  - 10: Bronze Badge
  - 25: Silver Badge
  - 50: Gold Badge
- **And Review for All**: Cast x review vote on each of all review queues in a single day. (Some queues have very few reviews waiting in the queue so not sure if numeric values are sufficient

  - 5: Bronze Badge
  - 15: Silver Badge
  - 40: Gold Badge

More can be added, but badges for both *good contribution* and *unsuccessful contribution attempt* must be added for balancing the contribution overcoming *badge hunter* problems.

Comment: Your "heedless" proposal is a non-starter. Badges are meant to encourage _good_ behavior.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178023/review-audit-badges for your first proposal

Comment: There is also [Tumbleweed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/tumbleweed) badge, which do not seem to encourage. That are ideas for new badges and **bad looking** may be removed from the list.

Comment: That badge doesn't encourage bad behavior.

Comment: Ok @Pëkka, I see your point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please no.

While the intentions of your suggestions are good, there have been *huge* problems with the review queue because of people gaming the system with garbage reviews for badges, causing incredible frustration.

If anything, we need to get *rid* of review badges.

See e.g. [The robo-approvers are killing my will to review edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155561)