# Review badges, we need more of them!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, badges

In the past a lot of people have argued to get rid of review badges all together. For example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216667/361484) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187351/abandon-the-review-grind-badges).

To an extent these questions are a bit old, and are based on different mechanics of the review system. But still, there are people that feel we shouldn't have badges for reviews.

**Reviewing is important**
There are a lot of posts, especially on bigger sites that hardly get any attention, and the only viable option of the subpar ones getting closed is the Close Vote review queue. On SO it will never be empty, so essentially we need more reviewers, especially ones as dedicated as [EdChum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401211/congratulations-to-edchum-for-100-000-close-reviews?cb=1). Now ofcourse there is a problem with people doing poor reviews, which was discussed a lot over the past few months, and features to remediate (at least part) of the issue [are being implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview).

**Badges**
Currently there are 3 review badges to be earned per queue:

- Custodian (bronze) - Complete at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type
- Reviewer (silver) - Complete at least 250 review tasks...
- Steward (gold) - Complete at least 1000 review tasks...

So after doing 1000 reviews in a queue the incentive to do more reviews ends. While we could really use more good reviewers.

Hence I propose we **add badges that award more reviews**, with incremental bigger gaps between them in terms of requirements. For example 2500, 5000, 10000 etc. As the current steward badge is already a gold badge these new badges would, of course, also be gold. Unless we are willing to implement something like platinum (which I don't see as very useful).

*Alternatively* we could make the steward badge be awarded for every 1000 reviews completed per review type.

Comment: related (duplicate?): [Improving Review Queues - Design overview II: Changing review bans and other new features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346903/165773) "Currently, the gold Steward badge is awarded once at 1,000 reviews per queue regardless of whether you’ve performed 1,000 or 10,000 reviews. We propose that reviewers can now earn this badge multiple times, adding more opportunities to earn badges while reviewing - this change is intended to be retroactive."

Comment: sharp as always @gnat. To think I just read that post before posting this...